# Why does Datomic yield the same temporary ID twice in a row when iterating?

Tags: clojure, datomic

This will produce two different ids, which is great:

```
#db/id[:db.part/user]
#db/id[:db.part/user]
```

but anything like the following (I tried a lot of ideas so far) will produce the same id twice, which is not what I want:

```
(repeatedly 2 (fn [] #db/id[:db.part/user]))
(for [n [1 2]] #db/id[:db.part/user])
```

All yield something like

```
(#db/id[:db.part/user -1000774] #db/id[:db.part/user -1000774])
```

where the number produced is the same for each call.

What I actually want is for the calls to NOT produce a number at all, so that I can just add the produced data via a transaction.

Any ideas?

Just to be clear, [the documentation](http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html) says, "Each call to tempid produces a unique temporary id."

[Edited after comment by @maxthoursie that `repeat` would be having this problem in any case.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d])
(repeatedly 2 #(d/tempid :db.part/user))
;; => (#db/id[:db.part/user -1000118] #db/id[:db.part/user -1000119])
```

Consider that #... are reader macros meaning that their value will be resolved when the expression is read which naturally happens only once. Use the #... macro only when you are writing literal transaction data (like a schema). Use datomic.api/tempid to generate tempids in runtime.

Comment: That did it, thanks.  Just stumbled across [literals_vs_code.clj](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/samples/literals_vs_code.clj) which shows code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Because repeat is repeating the value it got from calling id once.

Use repeatedly instead.

See examples at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/repeatedly

Comment: Thx, I forgot about that. But, we are not there yet and I might have to use the actual problematic code for my question, since `(repeatedly 2 (fn [] #db/id[:db.part/user]))` and `(for [n [1 2]] #db/id[:db.part/user])` both yield something like `(#db/id[:db.part/user -1000774] #db/id[:db.part/user -1000774])`, where the number produced is the same.

Comment: Ok, Sorry. Saw this text in the doc you linked to "If a given temporary id is used more than once in a given transaction, all instances are mapped to the same actual entity id." I guess that's the problem. But I know too little about datomic toprovide a solution.